# How can I reduce the bar group gaps between stacked bars in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am using the following code to generate a grouped-stacked bar plot using plotly. I want to decrease the gap between the grouped bars. How can I achieve this? In particular, I want to make the bars adjacent to each other with almost no gap between them.

Alternatively, can someone suggest a better way to get a group stacked bar grap like this with almost no gaps between the stacked bars of the group and the names of each bar being color coded in stead of the label names on x-axis?  [image]

```
rand_list = np.random.rand(30) # update this with original 

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        week=[1.2,1.2,1.3,1.3,1.6,1.6,1.7,1.7,4.4,4.4] * 3,
        layout=["abc","abc","def","def", "ghi", "ghi"] * 5,
        response=["0", "1"] * 15,
        cnt= list(rand_list),
    )
)
print(df)
fig = go.Figure()
fig.update_layout(
    template="simple_white",
    xaxis=dict(title_text="x-label"),
    yaxis=dict(title_text="y-label", showticklabels=False),
    barmode="stack",
)
colors = ["#2A66DE", "#FFC32B"]

for r, c in zip(df.response.unique(), colors):
    plot_df = df[df.response == r]
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Bar(x=[plot_df.week, plot_df.layout], y=plot_df.cnt, name=r, marker_color=c, width=0.2),
    )

fig
```

Comment: In addition to the answer, try adding the following code. `fig.update_layout(bargap=0);
fig.show()`

Answer (score 0):

> the bars adjacent to each other with ***almost*** no gap between them.

What about using `fig.update_traces` as follows

```
[...]

fig.update_traces(width=None)
fig.show()
```

[image]

As mentionned by @rbeginners, you may also want to control the gaps' width, doing:

```
fig.update_traces(width=None)
fig.update_layout(bargap=0)  # <---
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I also want the bars to have less width like in the figure I have showed in the figure. Can we control both the bar's width and the bar gap width?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works just fine. I was wondering if we could reduce the width of the bars as well.